# Changing default rails in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on Ubuntu . Initially I have 3 version of rails installed 3.2.9 , 3.2.12 and 4.0.0 . Running rail -v was showing Rails 4.0.0 . I tried to uninstall Rails 4.0.0 using gem uninstall rails 4.0.0 . Now Running gem uninstall rails gives this output:
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rails-3.2.9
 2. rails-3.2.12

Running rails -v now also gives Rails 4.0.0 .Any guesses how can i change default rail to 3.2.12.

Comment: join this chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34677/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-18011795-changing-default-rails-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigating more on **Thaha kp** comment, I found this:

```
  rails _3.2.12_ new myapp         # slightly different version positioning
```

that means, you can install as many `rails` versions you want in one `ruby` environment, and when you start a new app you just need to specify what version to use.

Now if you started your app in `rails 3.2.10` and want to upgrade to `rails 3.2.11` you just change the version in your `Gemfile` as **Bharath Sankar** suggested, after a running `bundle` your app will use `3.2.12` version.

Comment: Thanks Man.Keep In touch.